# Faster For Loop for Fuzzy Match

Tags: r, for-loop, fuzzy

Below is a simple script for fuzzy matching that i've written. There are about 24,000 keywords in the input file, and about 900,000 in the master list.

It currently is taking ages to process the 24,000 keywords.
Any ideas how i can eliminate the for loop in favor of something much faster?

```
> #=====Install Packages====# 
library(stringdist)
> 
> #=====Import Master List======# 
master_list =
> read.csv('/Documents/Keywords Search Terms
> Tool/input/master/Master List.csv')
> 
> #=====Import Input File=====# input_data =
> read.csv('/Documents/Keywords Search Terms
> Tool/input/test_input_file.csv')
> 
> #=====Fuzzy Matching for Keywords=====#
> #Convert to Characters 
master_list$Keyword<-as.character(master_list$Keyword)
> input_data$Keyword<-as.character(input_data$Keyword)
> 
> #Perform Matching 
fuzzy_match = data.frame()
> 
> for (i in 1:nrow(input_data)){   new_word = subset(input_data, Keyword
> == input_data$Keyword[i])   new_word$match_dummy = ain(new_word$Keyword,master_list$Keyword)   fuzzy_match <-
> rbind(fuzzy_match,new_word) }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try playing around with the stringdistmatrix function. It is parallelized.

```
library(stringdist)     
stringdistmatrix(c('a', 'b', 'c'), c('a', 'b', 'c'))
```

UPDATE based on comment:

Try something like:

```
ain(c('a', 'd'), c('a', 'b', 'c'))
```

This would yield:

```
TRUE FALSE
```

Comment: Thanks but that wouldn't work if i don't have the same number of records in each data set. Also i want to output a new field in the input list that designates whether there was a match or not.